# Eclipse Juno and install Maven surefire plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm learning Maven, and I have a sample project with a simple pom.
I want too add the surefire plugin so I may run junit tests.
I'm assuming that I can somehow add the plugin using Eclipse, or do I need to use the command line?

Comment: When you will launch mvn test, the plugin will be automatically installed. Nothing has to be done manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse/) which contains the surefire plugin.

The screenshot give below contains the "Run As" -> "Maven Test" option  which will invoke the surefire plugin.

[image: Screenshot of m2eclipse Run As option]

Comment: i have the option "Maven install", how do I tell it to install surefire, or any other non-installed plugin?

Comment: "Maven Test" will run your test code by invoking the surefire plugin. You don't have to install it separately.

Comment: In general, how do I install a plugin using "Maven install"

Comment: "Maven install" will install the artifact to the local repo. Read this for more info about the plugin : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/

Answer (score 3):

It seems the answer provided by @[Ajay George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/628943/ajay-george) is best, but if you're missing the pretty JUnit GUI with the red and green bars, refer to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392926/maven-surefire-arguments-when-running-junit-test-via-eclipse#comment21746544_12397172) by @[thSoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90874/thsoft):

> You can view Surefire's test reports in Eclipse's JUnit view if you
>   open the XML files in target/surefire-reports.